# How to stop a looping in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, laravel

I'm new in Laravel,
I want to make modal Iconpicker in js, but I got a problem that modal can't stop looping until the browser crashes.

and I don't get error at all on browser console, even on page load too:
[image: Modal Iconpicker]

script in fapicker.js:

```
(function() {
    this.fapicker = function (options = {})
    {
        var defaults = {
            iconUrl : '',
            onSelect: function(){}
        }

        var options = $.extend({}, defaults, options);

        if (!options.iconUrl) {
            console.log('faplugin: iconUrl must be defined');
        }

        $elm = $('[tabindex]').attr('data-tabindex', "-1");
        $elm.removeAttr('tabindex');

        var $modal = $('.fapicker-modal');
        if ($modal.length == 0) {
            var $modal = $('<div class="wdi-modal fapicker-modal">')
                    .append('<div class="wdi-modal-overlay">')
                    .appendTo('body');
            var $modal_container = $('<div class="wdi-modal-content">').appendTo($modal);
            var $modal_header = $('<div class="wdi-modal-header">').appendTo($modal_container);
            var $modal_body = $('<div class="wdi-modal-body">').appendTo($modal_container);
            var $search_field = $('<input type="search" placeholder="Search..." class="fapicker-search" />')
                                .attr('disabled', 'disabled')
                                .addClass('disabled')
                                .appendTo($modal_header);
            var $close = $('<button class="close"></button>').appendTo($modal_header);
            var $icon_container = $('<div class="fapicker-icons-container">').appendTo($modal_body);
            var $loader = $('<div class="loader-ring">').appendTo($icon_container);
            var $icon_notfound = $('<div class="fapicker-notfound">Icon not found</a>').hide().appendTo($icon_container);
            $.get(options.iconUrl, function (data) {

                var list_icon = jsyaml.load(data);
                var icon_name;
                var icons = [];

                $loader.hide();
```

```
                for(icon_name in list_icon)
                {
                    var styles = list_icon[icon_name].styles;
                    var i;
                    var prefix;

                    for (i in styles)
                    {
                        prefix = '';

                        switch (styles[i]) {
                            case 'solid':
                                prefix = 'fas';
                                break;
                            case 'brands':
                                prefix = 'fab';
                                break;
                            case 'regular':
                                prefix = 'far';
                                break;
                            case 'light':
                                prefix = 'far';
                                break;
                        }

                        if (prefix) {
                            var j;
                            var terms = list_icon[icon_name].search.terms.join() + ',' + icon_name;
                            var class_name = prefix + ' fa-' + icon_name;

                            var icon_item = '<a href="javascript:void(0)" title="'+list_icon[icon_name].label+' ('+class_name+')" data-icon="'+class_name+'" data-terms="'+terms+'"><i class="'+prefix+' fa-'+icon_name+'"></i></a>';
                            $icon_container.append(icon_item);
                        }
                    }
                }
```

```
      } else {

            var $icon_container = $modal.find('.fapicker-icons-container');
            var $icon_notfound =  $modal.find('.fapicker-notfound');
            // var $icon_filter = $icon_container.find('a[data-terms]');
            $modal.fadeIn('fast');
        }

        // Hack the close button on input type search
        var $icon_filter;
        $('.fapicker-search').on('input', function()
        {
            if (!$icon_filter) {
                $icon_filter = $icon_container.find('a[data-terms]');
            }

            $icon_notfound.hide();
            var val = $.trim(this.value.toLowerCase());
            $icon_filter.removeClass('fapicker-hidden');
            if (val) {
                $icon_filter.not('[data-terms *= "'+val+'"]').addClass("fapicker-hidden");
            }

            var $icon_found = $icon_filter.not('.fapicker-hidden');
            if (!$icon_found.length) {
                $icon_notfound.show();
            }
        });

        $('.fapicker-icons-container').on('click', 'a', function()
        {
            options.onSelect(this);
            $modal.fadeOut('fast');
        });

        $modal.find('.close').click(function() {
            $modal.fadeOut('fast');
        });
    }
}());
```

script in menu.js:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $(document).on('click', '.icon-preview', function() {
    $this = $(this);
        fapicker({
            iconUrl: "/vendors/font-awesome/metadata/icons.yml",
            onSelect: function (elm) {
                var icon_class = $(elm).data('icon');
                $this.find('i').removeAttr('class').addClass(icon_class);
                $this.parent().find('[name="icon_class"]').val(icon_class);
            } 
        });
    });
});
```

[image: path yml]

script in View:

```
<div class="mt-2 row form-group">
 <label for="icon" class="col-form-label col-md-3 fw-bolder text-muted">Use Icon</label>
   <div class="col-md-8 d-inline">
      <div class="row">
        <input type="hidden" name="icon_class" value="far fa-circle"/>
          <div class="col-md-4">
              <select class="form-select" id="icon">
                <option selected>Ya</option>
                <option value="1">Tidak</option>
              </select>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-8" style="margin-top: -5px; margin-left: -10px;">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="icon-preview text-muted" 
                  data-action="faPicker" style="font-size: 2rem;">
                  <i class="far fa-circle"></i>
            </a>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

the result should like this:
[image: result]

what should i do?

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow Denis, just to be sure you have no error at all on browser console? even on page load? also, `../../../../public/vendors/` have you tried to have shorter path?

Comment: Please add more information about the `fapicker` function respectively the package if you're using one. This allows a better insight on what goes wrong here.

Comment: @BagusTesa thanks,
yes, no error at all on browser console, even on page load too. I haven't tried it yet.
Sorry, I'm new in Laravel, would you please explain how to make a shorter path?

Comment: @frank so I want to make a button iconpicker in form modal bootstrap, when i click that button, it just loads and the function can't be closed, until the browser crashes.

Comment: what is the current url in the browser?

Comment: @BagusTesa http://127.0.0.1:8000/

Route:

Route::get('/', [MenuController::class, 'index']);

Comment: is `vendors` folder located on `127.0.0.1:800/vendors`? if yes, try replace that long path (the `.../../../../public/vendors/` thingy) with something like: `'/vendors/font-awesome/metadata/icons.yml'`. the thing is, when you do `php artisan serve` the `public` folder is your root `/`, so browser doesnt aware any folder above that. hope it helps.

Comment: @BagusTesa trying to replace that path with '/vendors/font-awesome/metadata/icons.yml', then i got an error like this :


Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)     :8000/[object%20HTMLInputElement]/public/vendors/font-awesome/metadata/icons.yml:1

Comment: hi denis, just wanted to be sure, `:8000/[object%20HTMLInputElement]/public/vendors/font-awesome/metadata/icons.yml` do you have any idea why theres an `[object%20HTMLInputElement]` in there? if you dont mind, could you share what library you used? i saw you add a lot of code, it may take sometime to digest.

Comment: @BagusTesa [object%20HTMLInputElement] because of ```url+``` ```iconUrl: url + "vendors/font-awesome/metadata/icons.yml" ``` , if I try delete that ```url +``` , then I don't get error but I get something like looping until my browser crashes/lag. Can I chat or dm your twitter?